# python3.7 aiohttp is slow

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, aiohttp

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import socket 

def _create_loop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop

async def _create_tasks(loop, URLs, func):
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=200, 
                                     limit_per_host=200, 
                                     force_close=True, 
                                     enable_cleanup_closed=True,
                                     family=socket.AF_INET, verify_ssl=False)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=connector) as session:
        semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(200)
        async with semaphore:
            tasks = [asyncio.create_task(func(session, URL)) for URL in URLs]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def _fetch_data_async(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.json()

loop = _create_loop()
tasks = _create_tasks(loop, URL_ls, _fetch_data_async)
results = loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
loop.close()
```

My API provider limits 200 per request. In fact, I have 1500 URLs to request. 
So Currently I'm splitting 1500 URL list into 8 so that each request number is less than 200.

I know that It's not the best way to handle this issue. 
If I send all 1500 URLs at once, the following error occurs.

```
> task: <Task pending coro=<_get_hist_inner2.<locals>._fetch_data_async() running at <ipython-input-22-f525394caccb>:47> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7ff0286eaf48>()]> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at /usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py:664]>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_get_hist_inner2.<locals>._fetch_data_async() running at <ipython-input-22-f525394caccb>:47> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7ff028706048>()]> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at /usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py:664]>
SSL error in data received
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7ff0281859b0>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=240 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 526, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 207, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.unwrap()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 767, in unwrap
    return self._sslobj.shutdown()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: KRB5_S_INIT] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2609)
```

Lastly, each API call takes 5 seconds to get the response. but 200 async call takes 1 minute to get the response...
I'm not sure if it's normal or is there any potential bottleneck in my code.

Anyhow, I need to call 1500 times very as fast as possible either by optimizing this code or using any available technology.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few things in your code that can be improved or need to be changed.

### 1. `_create_loop()`

This function is not needed nor should you want it. Notice the following:

- [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run): "*This function runs the passed coroutine, **taking care of managing the asyncio event loop** and finalizing asynchronous generators.*"
- [`asyncio.get_event_loop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop): "*Get the current event loop. **If there is no current event loop set in the current OS thread and set_event_loop() has not yet been called, asyncio will create a new event loop** and set it as the current one.*"

### 2. `_create_tasks()`

#### `asyncio.semaphore`

Without getting into details on why I don't believe this function should be created, let's talk about what can be fixed to have it properly running.

The following piece of code is not proper:

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=connector) as session:
        semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(200)
        async with semaphore:
            tasks = [asyncio.create_task(func(session, URL)) for URL in URLs]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Specifically the use of the [`asyncio.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore). The way this primitive work is by **bounding specific futures**, not by being initialized when you are creating tasks. In other words, proper use would be the following:

```py
import asyncio

async def func(sem):
    async with sem: # We wait for our Semaphore to release here. 
        print("Hey world!")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2) # We define the semaphore here. 
    tasks = [func(sem) for _ in range(10)]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

If you run the code above, you will notice "Hello World" (times two) will get printed every two seconds. This is because we are stating: "Only allocate this semaphore to two futures at a time. While they use the resource, do not release the semaphore."

#### `aiohttp.TCPConnector()`

Notice on the documentation for [`aiohttp.TCPConnector()`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#limiting-connection-pool-size) that the `limit` flag will "limit the amount of simultaneously opened connections." In other words, if you are setting this flag you don't need to create a `semaphore` to limit the number of connections you do simultaneously.

#### `asyncio.create_task()`

Easier to show this with an example. Run the following:

```py
import asyncio

async def func():
    print("In here.")
    return "Hello World!"

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(func()) for i in range(10)]

    # Notice that all of our tasks run before we gather them.
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print(await asyncio.gather(*tasks))

async def test():
    tasks = [func() for i in range(10)]

    # Notice that all of our tasks run AFTER we've defined a list of tasks.
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print(await asyncio.gather(*tasks))

asyncio.run(main())
print("\nRunning test.\n")
asyncio.run(test())
```

Notice that when you use `create_task()` you are actually running the future. To clarify why notice the following:

```py
import asyncio

async def async_func():
    return "Hello World!"


async def main():
    async_tasks = [async_func()]
    print(async_tasks) # > [<coroutine object async_func at 0x10c65f320>]
    await asyncio.gather(*async_tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

When you call an `async def` function, it actually returns a `coroutine` object that must called with either the loop or `asyncio`.

---

## Proper Function

So with the above in mind, we can fix your function. I've taken the liberty to re-write your entire program with the notes above, and some better conventions. What you do and how you edit it is up to you.

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

websites = """https://www.youtube.com
https://www.facebook.com
https://www.baidu.com
https://www.yahoo.com
https://www.amazon.com
https://www.wikipedia.org
http://www.qq.com
https://www.google.co.in
https://www.twitter.com
https://www.live.com
http://www.taobao.com
https://www.bing.com
https://www.instagram.com
http://www.weibo.com
http://www.sina.com.cn
https://www.linkedin.com
http://www.yahoo.co.jp
http://www.msn.com
http://www.uol.com.br
https://www.google.de
http://www.yandex.ru
http://www.hao123.com
https://www.google.co.uk
https://www.reddit.com
https://www.ebay.com
https://www.google.fr
https://www.t.co
http://www.tmall.com
http://www.google.com.br
https://www.360.cn
http://www.sohu.com
https://www.amazon.co.jp
http://www.pinterest.com
https://www.netflix.com
http://www.google.it
https://www.google.ru
https://www.microsoft.com
http://www.google.es
https://www.wordpress.com
http://www.gmw.cn
https://www.tumblr.com
http://www.paypal.com
http://www.blogspot.com
http://www.imgur.com
https://www.stackoverflow.com
https://www.aliexpress.com
https://www.naver.com
http://www.ok.ru
https://www.apple.com
http://www.github.com
http://www.chinadaily.com.cn
http://www.imdb.com
https://www.google.co.kr
http://www.fc2.com
http://www.jd.com
http://www.blogger.com
http://www.163.com
http://www.google.ca
https://www.whatsapp.com
https://www.amazon.in
http://www.office.com
http://www.tianya.cn
http://www.google.co.id
http://www.youku.com
https://www.example.com
http://www.craigslist.org
https://www.amazon.de
http://www.nicovideo.jp
https://www.google.pl
http://www.soso.com
http://www.bilibili.com
http://www.dropbox.com
http://www.xinhuanet.com
http://www.outbrain.com
http://www.pixnet.net
http://www.alibaba.com
http://www.alipay.com
http://www.chrome.com
http://www.booking.com
http://www.googleusercontent.com
http://www.google.com.au
http://www.popads.net
http://www.cntv.cn
http://www.zhihu.com
https://www.amazon.co.uk
http://www.diply.com
http://www.coccoc.com
https://www.cnn.com
http://www.bbc.co.uk
https://www.twitch.tv
https://www.wikia.com
http://www.google.co.th
http://www.go.com
https://www.google.com.ph
http://www.doubleclick.net
http://www.onet.pl
http://www.googleadservices.com
http://www.accuweather.com
http://www.googleweblight.com
http://www.answers.yahoo.com"""

async def get(url, session):
    try:
        async with session.get(url=url) as response:
            resp = await response.read()
            print("Successfully got url {} with resp of length {}.".format(url, len(resp)))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get url {} due to {}.".format(url, e.__class__))

async def main(urls):
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector()
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector)

    ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get(url, session) for url in urls])
    print("Finalized all. Return is a list of len {} outputs.".format(len(ret)))

    await session.close()

urls = websites.split("\n")
asyncio.run(main(urls))
```

Outputs:

```
Successfully got url http://www.google.com.br with resp of length 12475.
Successfully got url http://www.google.es with resp of length 12432.
Successfully got url http://www.google.it with resp of length 12450.
Successfully got url https://www.t.co with resp of length 0.
Successfully got url https://www.example.com with resp of length 1256.
Successfully got url https://www.google.fr with resp of length 12478.
Successfully got url https://www.google.de with resp of length 12463.
Successfully got url http://www.googleusercontent.com with resp of length 1561.
Successfully got url https://www.google.co.in with resp of length 11867.
Successfully got url https://www.google.co.uk with resp of length 11890.
Successfully got url https://www.google.ru with resp of length 12445.
Successfully got url https://www.bing.com with resp of length 97269.
Successfully got url https://www.facebook.com with resp of length 128029.
Successfully got url http://www.google.ca with resp of length 11803.
Successfully got url http://www.google.co.id with resp of length 12476.
Successfully got url https://www.google.co.kr with resp of length 12484.
Successfully got url https://www.instagram.com with resp of length 37967.
Successfully got url https://www.tumblr.com with resp of length 75321.
Successfully got url https://www.apple.com with resp of length 62405.
Successfully got url https://www.wikipedia.org with resp of length 76489.
Successfully got url https://www.whatsapp.com with resp of length 80930.
Successfully got url http://www.googleweblight.com with resp of length 0.
Successfully got url https://www.microsoft.com with resp of length 179346.
Successfully got url https://www.google.pl with resp of length 12447.
Successfully got url https://www.linkedin.com with resp of length 82074.
Successfully got url http://www.google.com.au with resp of length 11844.
Successfully got url http://www.googleadservices.com with resp of length 1561.
Successfully got url https://www.twitter.com with resp of length 327282.
Successfully got url http://www.163.com with resp of length 498893.
Successfully got url http://www.google.co.th with resp of length 12492.
Successfully got url https://www.stackoverflow.com with resp of length 117754.
Successfully got url http://www.accuweather.com with resp of length 268.
Successfully got url http://www.pinterest.com with resp of length 54089.
Successfully got url http://www.uol.com.br with resp of length 364068.
Successfully got url https://www.google.com.ph with resp of length 11874.
Successfully got url https://www.youtube.com with resp of length 301882.
Successfully got url https://www.wikia.com with resp of length 285727.
Successfully got url https://www.amazon.com with resp of length 545564.
Successfully got url https://www.wordpress.com with resp of length 87837.
Successfully got url http://www.cntv.cn with resp of length 3200.
Successfully got url https://www.live.com with resp of length 36964.
Successfully got url http://www.gmw.cn with resp of length 120034.
Successfully got url http://www.chrome.com with resp of length 161590.
Successfully got url https://www.netflix.com with resp of length 495818.
Successfully got url http://www.tianya.cn with resp of length 7888.
Successfully got url http://www.imgur.com with resp of length 4209.
Successfully got url https://www.twitch.tv with resp of length 89364.
Successfully got url http://www.msn.com with resp of length 47196.
Successfully got url https://www.cnn.com with resp of length 1136910.
Successfully got url http://www.doubleclick.net with resp of length 127443.
Successfully got url https://www.naver.com with resp of length 198837.
Successfully got url https://www.yahoo.com with resp of length 536726.
Successfully got url http://www.sohu.com with resp of length 205715.
Successfully got url http://www.office.com with resp of length 90082.
Successfully got url http://www.popads.net with resp of length 14548.
Successfully got url http://www.qq.com with resp of length 235514.
Successfully got url http://www.blogspot.com with resp of length 94478.
Successfully got url https://www.amazon.in with resp of length 449774.
Successfully got url http://www.imdb.com with resp of length 347893.
Successfully got url http://www.alibaba.com with resp of length 153300.
Successfully got url https://www.baidu.com with resp of length 158941.
Successfully got url https://www.amazon.co.jp with resp of length 435298.
Successfully got url https://www.aliexpress.com with resp of length 60278.
Successfully got url http://www.xinhuanet.com with resp of length 176985.
Successfully got url http://www.blogger.com with resp of length 94478.
Successfully got url https://www.amazon.co.uk with resp of length 672572.
Successfully got url http://www.paypal.com with resp of length 44020.
Successfully got url http://www.github.com with resp of length 133317.
Successfully got url http://www.dropbox.com with resp of length 271286.
Successfully got url https://www.amazon.de with resp of length 438965.
Successfully got url http://www.soso.com with resp of length 5816.
Successfully got url https://www.ebay.com with resp of length 301959.
Successfully got url http://www.answers.yahoo.com with resp of length 96590.
Successfully got url http://www.fc2.com with resp of length 34544.
Successfully got url https://www.reddit.com with resp of length 656718.
Successfully got url http://www.go.com with resp of length 733683.
Successfully got url http://www.chinadaily.com.cn with resp of length 102734.
Successfully got url http://www.craigslist.org with resp of length 59273.
Successfully got url http://www.bilibili.com with resp of length 95028.
Successfully got url http://www.zhihu.com with resp of length 45853.
Successfully got url http://www.yandex.ru with resp of length 114932.
Successfully got url https://www.360.cn with resp of length 74085.
Successfully got url http://www.tmall.com with resp of length 227590.
Successfully got url http://www.bbc.co.uk with resp of length 326671.
Successfully got url http://www.jd.com with resp of length 18105.
Successfully got url http://www.outbrain.com with resp of length 48191.
Successfully got url http://www.pixnet.net with resp of length 6295.
Successfully got url http://www.diply.com with resp of length 762463.
Successfully got url http://www.booking.com with resp of length 445064.
Successfully got url http://www.nicovideo.jp with resp of length 106691.
Successfully got url http://www.onet.pl with resp of length 778449.
Successfully got url http://www.yahoo.co.jp with resp of length 18107.
Successfully got url http://www.hao123.com with resp of length 304041.
Successfully got url http://www.alipay.com with resp of length 21561.
Successfully got url http://www.ok.ru with resp of length 138096.
Successfully got url http://www.coccoc.com with resp of length 46725.
Successfully got url http://www.taobao.com with resp of length 393906.
Successfully got url http://www.sina.com.cn with resp of length 546781.
Successfully got url http://www.weibo.com with resp of length 96263.
Successfully got url http://www.youku.com with resp of length 582773.
Finalized all. Return is a list of len 100 outputs.
```

In only a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation with a cleaner code sample. It was extremely helpful