# Asynchronous method containing Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, concurrency

In my controller, the`[POST]` methods usually call a Stored Procedure from the database. I am wondering if I am doing the right thing in order to avoid concurrency issues. Take the following method as example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Phase phase)
    {
        int releaseId = (int)TempData["id"];
        string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "CreatePhase";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // adding parameters
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Name",
                    Value = phase.Name,
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                    Size = 50
                };
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                parameter = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@ReleaseId",
                    Value = releaseId,
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
                };
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                connection.Open();
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Phase", new { id = releaseId });
    }
```

Is `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` the proper way to avoid concurrency? Does it have any effect? Are there any better ways of achieving this or is this good enough?

Comment: as a side note: you don't have to close the connection manually when you are using it with 'using' statement, the 'using' statement will close it anyway

Comment: No, `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` has nothing to do with concurrency issues. It is also not clear why you want to *avoid* concurrency, usually people strive to *achieve* it.

Comment: @GSerg then does it even help me in any way? How can I deal with concurrency issues?

Comment: What do you mean by concurrency issues to begin with?

Comment: For example - 2 users want to update a `Phase` at the same time (in the original post I put the `Create()` method, though). By "concurrency issues" I understand that if both users want to update simultaneously, it won't allow them.

Comment: It will allow them. It is a basic feature of any database. Now, what will happen as a result of that update depends on what you do inside the stored procedure and how you do it. You can "solve" all concurrency issues by always setting all your connections isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`, but then you will have no concurrency, which is not good for you. The topic of correctly writing stored procedures to allow concurrency and avoid deadlocks and dirty reads is too big for a question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async has nothing to do with concurrency. In fact, if anything, it adds to concurrency issues, since there's no defined order to operations with async, hence "asynchronous". However, in a multi-thread environment like a web app, concurrency is an issue, sync or async, because each of the 1000 or so threads can be doing the same work simultaneously.

There's only two real ways to handle concurrency: locks and concurrency tokens. Concurrency tokens are the best method, but they only work for things that are existing (not inserts). Basically, you have a column that stores the concurrency token, and each time there's an operation on that row, the token is updated. Then, before you actually perform an operation, you check that the token is the same as when you got the row in the first place (meaning nothing has changed). If so, then you can proceed with the operation. If not, then something else has modified it, and thus, it's no longer safe to go ahead. This check is done through a where clause. For example:

```
update Foos set Bar = 'Baz' where Id = 1 and Version = {token}
```

If the token in `Version` is no longer the same, then obviously no row will match and nothing is updated. You can then use the returned count of operations (i.e. zero) to determine that there was a concurrency failure, and recover.

This won't work with an insert, because there's nothing to key off of to determine whether or not a change has occurred. (You can't employ a where clause in an insert.) For that situation, you have no choice but to use locks to prevent anything else from happening while you're doing the operation. However, locks will absolutely kill your throughput, as it essentially forces subsequent requests to queue up and they can only be processed one at a time. As such, you should avoid these types of operations entirely when concurrency is an issue. (Inserts that don't conflict with each other are fine.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a small question, though - for a small system where chances are small that users will do the same thing at once, I assume it would be alright if I don't take measures against concurrency, as, in this case, the throughput is more important. Also, would serializing the stored procedures help in any way?

Comment: Never assume concurrency won't be an issue. Even with sites with large numbers of users operations like this usually take only a matter of milliseconds. Yet, still a concurrency conflict can occur during that time. It's all about timing. Your site could only have two active users, but if those two active users just happen to do the same thing at the same time, you're boned. If you know there's potential for a concurrency conflict, then you need to plan for that, and have a way to recover.

Answer (score 0):

First of all asynchronous is not concurrency or multithreading but improves throughput. Are you trying to solve concurrency or throughput? Throughput means many requests invoke the process without waiting for another one to complete. Concurrency means having multiple workers (threads) to run in concurrent to complete a process. Looking at your example you don't need multiple threads as the process is not processor bounded but I/O bounded so single-threaded asynchronous operation would be fine

If you want your code to be asynchronous the "await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();" correct as you are doing an I/O operation and it will not hold the thread until the I/O operation completes. As soon as it hits "await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();" it will release the thread to the caller and once the operation completes it returns controls the thread which was executing before.

Please find an excellent answer here,

[What is the difference between asynchronous programming and multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680985/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-programming-and-multithreading/34681101#34681101)  and an excellent article https://exceptionnotfound.net/async-await-in-asp-net-csharp-ultimate-guide/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Right - so these async methods won't solve the concurrency issues. What would, though?

Comment: Are you trying to solve concurrency or throughput? Throughput means many requests invoke the process without waiting for another one to complete. Concurrency means having multiple workers (threads) to run in concurrent to complete a process. Looking at you example you don't need multiple threads as the process is not processor bounded but I/O bounded so single-threaded asynchronous operation would be fine

Comment: Awesome! So concurrency shouldn't be a problem. Then, from what I understand, the throughput part is fixed by the `await`?

Comment: yes await will fix the problem of holding the thread, which increases the throughput