# Skipped 675 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. How to make app run process in background without freezing the UI?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, feed

I have an news aggregator and in debug i have the following:
Skipped 675 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I am loading only from 12 sites. Is there a way to to do all this loading in background without the whole app freezing?

EDIT:
Method to get one news

```
public async static Task<NewsContent> oneNews(string category,string site)
    {
        if(sites.Count==0)
            addElements();

        GetNews gn = new GetNews(site,false);
        Random rn = new Random();

        var s = await gn.news(rn.Next(0,2));
        return s;
    }
```

The GetNews class:

```
class GetNews
{

    string url;
    bool isMultiple;
    public GetNews(string url,bool isMultiple)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.isMultiple = isMultiple;
    }


    public async Task<NewsContent> news(int i)
    {
        List<NewsContent> feedItemsList = new List<NewsContent>();

        try
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(stream);
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("dc", xmlDocument.DocumentElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("dc"));
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("content", xmlDocument.DocumentElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("content"));
            XmlNodeList itemNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
            NewsContent feedItem = new NewsContent();

                if (itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("title") != null)
                {
                    feedItem.title = itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
                }
                if (itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("link") != null)
                {
                    feedItem.url = itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("link").InnerText;
                }
                if (itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("pubDate") != null)
                {
                    var time = itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("pubDate").InnerText;
                    feedItem.time = getHour(time);
                }
                if (itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("description") != null)
                {
                    feedItem.desc = itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("description").InnerText;

                }
                if (itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("content:encoded", nsmgr) != null)
                {
                    feedItem.content = itemNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("content:encoded", nsmgr).InnerText;
                }
                else
                {
                    feedItem.content = feedItem.desc;
                }
                feedItem.imageURL = getImage(feedItem.content);


                var sourcename = url.Split(new[] { "//" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
                feedItem.newsSource = sourcename.Split(new[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                if (feedItem.content.Contains("<p>"))
                {
                    var shortContent = feedItem.content.Split(new[] { "<p>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
                    string finalShortContent = "";
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < shortContent.Length; ii++)
                    {
                        if (ii > 200 && shortContent[ii].Equals(' '))
                            break;
                        while (shortContent[ii].Equals('<') || shortContent[ii].Equals('p') || shortContent[ii].Equals('/') || shortContent[ii].Equals('>'))
                            ii++;
                        try
                        {
                            finalShortContent += shortContent[ii];
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    finalShortContent += "...";
                    feedItem.shortcontent = finalShortContent;
                }
            return feedItem;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
    string getImage(string full)
    {
        try
        {
            var code = full.Split(new[] { "src=\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
            var fin = code.Split(new[] { "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
            return fin;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    List<int> getHour(string full)
    {
        try
        {
            List<int> smh = new List<int>();
            var ph = full.Split(new[] { "2020 " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
            var hour = ph.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            smh.Add(Int32.Parse(hour[0]));
            smh.Add(Int32.Parse(hour[1]));
            var second = hour[2].Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
            smh.Add(Int32.Parse(second));
            return smh;
        }catch(Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  Use a task.  There are thousands of examples of using a Task to do background processing

Comment: I added a task to every single function included. It didn’t do a difference. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I have no idea, because you didn't bother to post any of the relevant code

Comment: Sorry, i am new here, just added some code, Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680985/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-programming-and-multithreading

Comment: There are networking libraries that can manage threading these requests for you and capturing responses. Also good parsing libraries. Seems like there is some reinventing of the wheel going on here. https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request or https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/cronet/start might be a good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should put the function in another thread

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        //function
                    });
```