# Is Javascript async and await the equivalent to mulithreading?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous

Is using `async` and `await` the crude person's threads?

Many moons ago I learned how to do multithreaded Java code on Android. I recall I had to create threads, start threads, etc.

Now I'm learning Javascript, and I just learned about `async` and `await`.

For example:

```
async function isThisLikeTwoThreads() {
 const a = slowFunction();
 const b = fastFunction();
 console.log(await a, await b);
}
```

This looks way simpler than what I used to do and is a lot more intuitive.

`slowFunction()` would start first, then `fastFunction()` would start, and `console.log()` would wait until both functions resolved before logging - and `slowFunction()` and `fastFunction()` are potentially running at the same time. I expect it's ultimatly on the browser whether or not thesea are seperate threads. But it looks like it walks and talks like crude multithreading. Is it?

Comment: _Javascript is a single threaded language_

Comment: Not really, no. The `async` and `await` stuff is basically just syntax sugar for constructing a generator-based mechanism for managing Promise instances.

Comment: If `slowFunction()` and `fastFunction()` are asynchronous functions, it's assumed that they are suspended, waiting on a signal to re-enter the event loop. They are not CPU-bounded functions running in separate threads.

Comment: @NikitaMadeev - That's a dramatic oversimplification. :-)

Comment: @Pointy - You don't have to `await` just when doing a function call. In the OP's code above, for instance, if `slowFunction` and `fastFunction` both start asynchronous processes, the above starts both and allows them to run in parallel, then waits for them both to complete before doing the `console.log`. If the OP had used `const a = await longFunction(); const b = await slowFunction();`, they'd be done one after another instead; `fastFunction` wouldn't start its process until `slowFunction`'s finished. I've definitely done that in real code (not just with `Promise.all` :-) ).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well yea that's true I guess, it can be any expression and it behaves "promise-like" when the expression evaluates to a Promise. I don't get to use `async/await` in my environment so I try and keep it simple.

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680985/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-programming-and-multithreading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is using `async` and `await` the crude person's threads?

No, not at all. It's just syntax sugar *(really, really useful sugar)* over using promises, which in turn is just a *(really, really useful)* formalized way to use callbacks. It's useful because you can wait asynchronously (without blocking the JavaScript main thread) for things that are, by nature, asynchronous (like HTTP requests).

If you need to use threads, use [web workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), [Node.js worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), or whatever multi-threading your environment provides. Per specification (nowadays), only a single thread *at a time* is allowed to work within a given JavaScript "realm" (very loosely: the global environment your code is running in and its associated objects, etc.) and so only a single thread at a time has access to the variables and such within that realm, but threads can cooperate via messaging (including transferring objects between them without making copies) and [shared memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer).

> For example:
>
> ```
> async function isThisLikeTwoThreads() {
>  const a = slowFunction();
>  const b = fastFunction();
>  console.log(await a, await b);
> }
> ```

Here's what that code does when `isThisLikeTwoThreads` is called:

1. `slowFunction` is called **synchronously** and its return value is assigned to `a`.
2. `fastFunction` is called **synchronously** and its return value is assigned to `b`.
3. When `isThisLikeTwoThreads` reaches `await a`, it wraps `a` in a promise (as though you did `Promise.resolve(a)`) and returns a new promise (not that same one). Let's call the promise wrapped around `a` "`aPromise`" and the promise returned by the function "`functionPromise`".
4. Later, when `aPromise` settles, if it was rejected `functionPromise` is rejected with the same rejection reason and the following steps are skipped; if it was fulfilled, the next step is done
5. The code in `isThisLikeTwoThreads` continues by wrapping `b` in a promise (`bPromise`) and waiting for that to settle
6. When `bPromise` settles, if it was rejected `functionPromise` is rejected with the same rejection reason; if it was fulfilled, the code in `isThisLikeTwoThreads` continues by logging the fulfillment values of `aPromise` and `bPromise` and then fulfilling `functionPromise` with the value `undefined`

All of the work above was done on the JavaScript thread where the call to `isThisLikeTwoThreads` was done, but it was spread out across multiple "jobs" (JavaScript terminology; the HTML spec calls them "tasks" and specifies [a fair bit of detail](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops) for how they're handled on browsers). If `slowFunction` or `fastFunction` started an asynchronous process and returned a promise for that, that asynchronous process (for instance, an HTTP call the browser does) may have continued in parallel with the JavaScript thread while the JavaScript thread was doing other stuff or (if it was also JavaScript code on the main thread) may have competed for other work on the JavaScript thread (competed by adding jobs to the job queue and the thread processing them in a loop).

But using promises doesn't add threading. :-)

Comment: (FWIW, I go into the above in some detail in my new book. Promises are in Chapter 8, `async`/`await` in Chapter 9, and shared memory in Chapter 16. See my profile for links if you're interested.)

Comment: nice answer @T.J. Crowder, is it safe to say that async/await is a model for concurrency in JavaScript, though it is not necessarily multi-threaded? - trying to wrap my head around it, thanks

Comment: @phoenixdown - That's an interesting question. Yeah, I guess so. For instance, [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/54kLf6se/), `a` and `b` are definitely running concurrently. So yes, I'd say [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) but **not** [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing), since although `a` and `b` overlap, they never do something in the same instant. (For that you need a worker thread.) Beware, though, that I don't have a formal computer science education. But to my understanding of the terms, yes, I think that's right.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read this to understand that the answer is no: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

To summarize, the runtime uses multiple threads for internal operations (network, disk... for a Node.js environment, rendering, indexedDB, network... for a browser environment) but the JavaScript code you wrote and the one you imported from different libraries will always execute in a single thread. Asynchronous operations will trigger callbacks which will be queued and executed one by one.

Basically what happens when executing this function:

```
async function isThisLikeTwoThreads() {
 const a = slowFunction();
 const b = fastFunction();
 console.log(await a, await b);
}
```

Execute `slowFunction`.
Execute `fastFunction`.
Enqueue the rest of the code (`console.log(await a, await b)`) when `a` promise and `b` promise have resolved. The `console.log` runs in the same thread **after** `isThisLikeTwoThreads` has returned, and **after** the possible enqueued callbacks have returned. Assuming `slowFunction` and `fastFunction` both return promises, this is an equivalent of:

```
function isThisLikeTwoThreads() {
 const a = slowFunction();
 const b = fastFunction();
 a.then(aResult => b.then(bResult => console.log(aResult, bResult)));
}
```

Comment: It's a little confusing to name your promises and your resolved values the same. And while it is _functionally_ equivalent to what you've written (other than forgetting to return the `Promise.all()` expression, and returning errors thrown synchronously by `slowFunction()` and `fastFunction()` as a rejected promise), it's actually a "strict" equivalent of: `return Promise.resolve(a).then(_a => Promise.resolve(b).then(_b => { console.log(_a, _b); }));`

Comment: If `a` and `b` are native promise objects then that's correct, otherwise `Promise.resolve()` is not a no-op. I guess for the sake of simplicity it's close enough though, I just prefer not to use the word "strict" when it's not actually true.

Comment: Yeah but if OP wrote `await` in front of them that supposes they return a `Promise`. I'll clarify it

Comment: `await` actually does insert an explicit `Promise.resolve()` call to convert a thenable into a promise ([step 2 of 6.2.3.1 `await`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#await)) **edit** feel free to ignore this, just saw you removed "strict"

Comment: I know it does, my goal was just to write equivalent simple code in case `a` and `b` contain native promises

Answer (score 0):

Similar but not the same. Javascript will only ever be doing 'one' thing at a time. It is fundamentally single-threaded. That said, it can appear odd as results may appear to be arriving in different orders - exacerbated by functions such as async and await.

For example, even if you're rendering a background process at 70fps there are small gaps in rendering logic available to complete promises or receive event notifications -- it's during these moments promises are completed giving the illusion of multi-threading.

If you REALLY want to lock up a browser try this:

```
let a = 1;

while (a == 1){
    console.log("doing a thing");
}
```

You will never get javascript to work again and chrome or whatever will murder your script. The reason is when it enters that loop - nothing will touch it again, no events will be rendered and no promises will be delivered - hence, single threading.

If this was a true multithreaded environment you could break that loop from the outside by changing the variable to a new value.