# Get the first received value from an iterator of channels in rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, future, channel, rust-tokio

I have an iterator of `futures::channel::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<T>`. I want to handle every answer of the receiver, only one at a time, but while also handling other futures.

This should be possible by looping over a futures::select!. But I need some way of getting a resolved value from the `UnboundReceiver<T>`.
I've attempted to use `futures::future::select_all(Iter)`, but this fails to compile with the error: `futures::channel::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<T> is not a future`.

Playground example is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6d3924a04ba7565b9a22e25d8ab25f9a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

futures::channel::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver implements `Stream` but isn't a future, so you can create a `SelectAll` by calling `futures::stream::select_all(recv)` and then resolve to the next ready message by calling `select_all.next()`.
I adapted your example by using it:

```rust
use futures::{channel::mpsc, stream::{self, StreamExt, select_all}}; // 0.3.8
use tokio; // 1.0.1

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> failure::Fallible<()> {
    let mut recv = Vec::new();
    let mut futures = stream::FuturesUnordered::new();
    for _i in 0..3 {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::unbounded();
        recv.push(rx);
        futures.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
            tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(3000)).await;
            tx.unbounded_send("Message").unwrap();
        }));
    }
    let mut select_all = select_all(recv);
    loop {
        futures::select! {
            msg = select_all.next() => {
                println!("{:#?}", msg);
            }
            _ = futures.select_next_some() => {
                eprintln!("Thread died");
            },
            complete => break
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Note that this is not multithreading but asynchronous programming, you spawn aynchronous tokio tasks instead of threads.
I recommend reading the answer here: [What is the difference between asynchronous programming and multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680985/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-programming-and-multithreading)