# JavaScript promise blocking code execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

Could someone try and help me to understand why the first function is non-blocking while the second one blocks the rest of the code? Isn't `Promise.resolve` the same as resolving from a `new Promise`? I can't quite wrap my head around it.

```js
function blockingCode() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2500000000; i++) {
      // Doing nothing...
    }
    resolve('ping');
  });
}

function nonBlockingCode() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2500000000; i++) {
      // Doing nothing...
    }
    return 'pong';
  });
}

console.time('non-blocking');
nonBlockingCode().then((message) => console.log(message));
console.timeEnd('non-blocking');

// console.time('blocking');
// blockingCode().then((message) => console.log(message));
// console.timeEnd('blocking');
```

Comment: That's not quite right. They both block while the loop is executing. The only difference is when the returned promise resolves. Also, `.then((message) => console.log(message))` can just be `.then(console.log)`

Comment: The names of your functions are confusing given the content of the question.

Comment: Please note that promises is not concurrency, although it does enable it (using things like workers)

Comment: @evolutionxbox they are indeed *concurrent*, they are not *parallel*.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no prob. [legendary explanation of the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680985/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-programming-and-multithreading/34681101#34681101)

Comment: Your first function is equivalent to `for (let i = 0; i < 2500000000; i++) {} return Promise.resolve('ping');`

Answer (score 2):

The two functions are actually blocking.

You have the illusion that the second one isn't blocking because calling `Promise.resolve().then()` adds one more round to the event loop, so `console.timeEnd('non-blocking');` is reached before the code inside your promise even starts.

You will notice that both function block if you fix your code like this:

```js
console.time('non-blocking');
nonBlockingCode()
.then((message) => console.log(message))
.then(() => console.timeEnd('non-blocking'));
```

Note that a promise is intended not to block when the time-consuming logic inside the promise is delegated to a third-party, and you just wait for the result (e.g. when a client does a call to a remote database, a remote web server, etc.).

If you are having a hard time with promises and `then` logic, have a look at the [async / await syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#r%C3%A9%C3%A9crire_une_cha%C3%AEne_de_promesses_avec_une_fonction_asynchrone), I find it much easier to understand.