# Task.WhenAll parallel

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I am calling 10 different points from the api in `OnInitializedAsync()` in Blazor WASM

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

var oneTask = OneAsync();
var twoTask = TwoAsync();

tasks.add(oneTask)
tasks.add(twoTask);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var result = await oneTask;
```

but I suspect it is doing it one by one according to the developer console. I see the call to each point and how long each one takes, shouldn't I run it all at once??

Am I doing something wrong or I don't understand the use of `WhenAll`?

Comment: How would that single call look like? To what URL would it be to begin with?

Comment: I mean run all tasks at once

Comment: They are in flight at once. Each will complete in its time. When the last one completes, WhenAll completes. This is not specific to Blazor.

Comment: But doesn't it run in parallel? from what I am understanding it is as if there was a foreach and it was making a call for each

Comment: They run concurrently. That [does not mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34681101/11683) they run on different threads.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` does not change how the tasks were created or scheduled, it simply waits for them all to be completed. You need to look at the code that starts your tasks for indications as to why it (seems to) execute them sequentially. It's certainly not Task.WhenAll's fault.

Comment: I have edited my question with what I am using.

Comment: @Angelru You are using it correctly except for the last line where you are repeating the call to `OneAsync` and waiting for it again. Otherwise all tasks in the list run concurrently.

Comment: @GSerg I was confused, I have returned to edit. This is how I am using it.

Comment: WhenAll returns the results already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___

Comment: @Angelru That's fine then, apart from the minor optimization mentioned by Fildor.

Comment: Note that OneAsync and TwoAsync will run synchronously up to the first await that doesn't immediately return a completed result - this may explain your "one by one" results

Comment: The console will display results one by one. It cannot do anything else. Even when they all complete at the same time, they will be printed one by one.