# Why Task needs to use ManualResetEventSlim internally?

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library, thread-synchronization

According to the source code of `Task` https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1483

So `Task` uses `ManualResetEventSlim` kernel synchronization construct internally

```
internal ManualResetEventSlim CompletedEvent
{
    get
    {
        ContingentProperties contingentProps = EnsureContingentPropertiesInitialized();
        if (contingentProps.m_completionEvent == null)
        {
            bool wasCompleted = IsCompleted;
            ManualResetEventSlim newMre = new ManualResetEventSlim(wasCompleted);  // <----------------
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref contingentProps.m_completionEvent, newMre, null) != null)
            {
                // Someone else already set the value, so we will just close the event right away.
                newMre.Dispose();
            }
            else if (!wasCompleted && IsCompleted)
            {
                // We published the event as unset, but the task has subsequently completed.
                // Set the event's state properly so that callers don't deadlock.
                ContingentProperties.SetEvent(newMre);
            }
        }

        return contingentProps.m_completionEvent;
    }
}
```

But isn't that running a Task means threadpool places the "work item" (represented as Task in high level) to the global/local queue then it will picked up by a worker thread to run? is there a need to use any kernel thread synchronization construct? I mean it synchronize with whom? what's the purpose of using a kernel construct here?

Comment: the comment immediately above where you've cut: highlights that this is specifically in the IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle scenario; I don't know the logic here, but: this isn't the majority case

Comment: `isn't that running a Task means threadpool places the "work item" to the global/local queue` - [no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34680985/11683).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a need to use any kernel thread synchronization construct?

Yes, for the [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) method. When you call `Wait`, you want to block the current thread until the `Task` completes on another thread. The [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim) performs the role of blocking the current thread, until a signal comes from the completing thread so that the current thread can be unblocked.

> Isn't that running a `Task` means threadpool places the "work item" (represented as Task in high level) to the global/local queue then it will picked up by a worker thread to run?

This is the case with the [delegate-based tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html), that were introduced with the .NET Framework 4.0 at 2010. The next .NET release (.NET Framework 4.5 at 2012) introduced the `async`/`await` technology, that made promise-style tasks more prominent. These tasks can represent anything and not just the completion of a delegate. Most tasks today fall in the second category. For example the [`File.ReadAllTextAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltextasync) returns a promise-style `Task`. There is [no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) tied to the `Task` for the majority of the time that this operation is in-flight.

Comment: Promise style tasks weren't exclusive to .NET 4.5.  They became more prevalent due to `async` method existing to make it much easier to create them, but they existed and were quite common with the introduction of `Task` in 4.0.

Comment: @Servy you are right. I updated the answer accordingly.