async / await useful when independent network calls shouldn't block each other
My understanding of Python's asyncio library (and async functions for Python in general) is that it uses threads. These threads are not processes, so division of CPU and parallelization is not possible.
However, if an application method has two network calls, A and B, it might be appropriate.    If A must finish before B starts then it's my understanding that using async/await syntax is wasted effort. However, if A and B are independent (neither response is an input to the other), then async / await syntax could indeed be useful. The reasoning is that the execution of network call A is idle time, blocking the start of network call B. Async / await would allow B to begin before A's response is received.
I could be wrong but this is my understanding. Increasingly, I'm seeing FastAPI tutorials, blogs, etc use async / await in contexts where it's assumedly not harmful to performance but not useful either. One example. A number of these calls are directed to the service's own relational database. This might complicate when async / await is/isn't useful.
Is my understanding accurate?

"My understanding of Python's asyncio library is that it uses threads" no. Or rather, not necessarily. "These threads are not processes, so division of CPU and parallelization is not possible" that's also wrong, threads can and do run on different CPUs, although again asyncio doesn't necessarily use threads. You're understanding of when to chose asyncio is basically correct though: any time you have an I/O bound process with lots of idle time (e.g. waiting for user input, waiting for a TLS handshake, etc etc) wrapping it in an async task can let other code run.

Not written about Python per se, but you may find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/34681101/3757232

@JaredSmith I'll read more on the guts of asyncio, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! At any rate, it doesn't sound that asyncio allows the user to parallelize multiple CPU-bound tasks - which I believe is what the author of the linked application is trying to accomplish

That is correct, for CPU-bound tasks... well normally in most languages you'd use multithreading but Python has the GIL so you'd want to use the multiprocessing module from the standard library.

Ah okay, I had heard that Java could parallelize with threads but Python could not. Thanks for the explanation!

That is correct. One last potential misunderstanding to clear up: I just looked at the example. The author is correct to use asyncio, and you are incorrect about the code being CPU rather than I/O bound. Talking to a database is I/O. Talking to a another service (even one of your own!) is I/O. Crunching a bunch of numbers with numpy is NOT I/O. This is why numpy isn't written entirely in Python.

Okay, sorry to belabor the point but I think I get it now!! Suppose a simple application with two async API methods, hello and lookup. Hello just returns the string "hello" whereas lookup performs a Db operation (I/O as you noted.) Now suppose that the application receives two requests around the same time; the first pings lookup, the second pings hello. Given your helpful comments, I believe that while lookup awaits a Db response, the application should be able to service the hello request (2nd request not blocked by 1st.)

Yup I think you get it now. I'll write all this up as an answer, please accept if that works for you!


My understanding of Python's asyncio library is that it uses threads

No. Or rather, not necessarily. Asynchrony isn't about threads.

These threads are not processes, so division of CPU and parallelization is not possible

Also wrong, threads can and do run on different CPUs, although again asyncio doesn't necessarily use threads. Parallelization cannot be done with threads in Python because of the GIL but that isn't applicable to multithreading in general. If you want true parallel processing, look at the multiprocessing module from the standard library.
Your understanding of when to chose asyncio is basically correct though: any time you have an I/O bound process with lots of idle time (e.g. waiting for user input, waiting for a TLS handshake, etc etc) wrapping it in an async task can let other code run. Consider the code in the example you linked:

Talking to a database is I/O*
Talking to a another service (even one of your own!) is I/O

In addition to those things like

Taking user input (I/O)
Talking to the file system or operating system (I/O)

are the kinds of things asyncio tends to be good for.
For contrast, crunching a bunch of numbers with numpy is not I/O. If you need to crunch a bunch of numbers, and the calculation is able to be independently parallelized, then you want to use parallelism with multiprocessing.
* Note that while the database itself might be CPU-bound, querying it over a socket (remote or local) is I/O: you spend most of your time waiting for the response packets at the application layer.
